# Maven generates no class files

Tags: maven

I have a maven build setup that has worked well for a long time. But now I cannot build.

Even though maven writes

```
Compiling 194 source files to /projects/project/target/classes
```

No classes are found in target/classes afterwards. The resources are copied but no classes are compiled?

I checkout out the maven debug output, etc. and everything looks correct I think.

There is no error emitted from maven (except for the test classes not being able to compile, since they are dependent on the classes that were never compiled in the first place).

Pom: http://pastebin.com/QeNrJJnY

mvn compile output: http://pastebin.com/7v7EABbU

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Can you show your pom.xml?

Comment: Edit: pom.xml and mvn compile output added.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that compilation errors where occuring, even though they could not be seen anywhere.

I compiled with another tool, found and fixed compilation errors in the code, and now the maven build seems to work.

Comment: Which other tool did you use?

Comment: Indeed it was a hidden compile issue. I had incorrect template parameters in a class declaration. Maybe that will help someone.